Users of [Hikvision] devices reusing [isapi] and [lpr] tags
A company called Hikvision is making networked security cameras (IP cameras). They offer an API to their devices they call "Intelligent Security Application Programming Interface" (ISAPI).
Users asking questions on SO have been reusing the isapi tag which is originally for Microsoft's IIS web server (ISAPI on Wikipedia).

we already have hikvision
isapi has 21 watchers, not very lively
is:question [isapi] -hikvision currently 402 questions
is:question [isapi] hikvision was least 8 questions, already fixed

Further, their cameras seem to be usable for automatic license plate recognition (ALPR), or license plate readers (LPR). The users of Hikvision seem to just tag their questions with lpr, which is about printers.

We already have automatic-license-plate-recognition
lpr has a mere 6 watchers and 78 questions in total. It's an ex-tag.
is:question [lpr] -hikvision 75 questions
is:question [lpr] hikvision was 3 questions, already fixed

What to do?
I just saw this because I monitor the ALPR tag, a "subtag" of computer-vision. I'll retag the stuff right now but this is going to keep happening. I don't want to be responsible for tags I have no interest in (ISAPI, line printers). I also don't know if this is even considered an issue that needs a resolution.

We should probably have tags called [tag:hikvision-isapi] and [tag:hikvision-lpr] -- that's the standard procedure for ambiguous tags: the new one gets its own tag with "vendor-product" syntax. We could also look to see whether there are any tags for competitor products and similar offerings, e.g. Axis-LPR or Avigilon-LPR or anything.

I think such specific tags serve no purpose. there's hardly any watchers on the hikvision tag itself (19 right now), and those would have even fewer. besides that, I highly doubt the hikvision users will care to use those tags. they're mostly new accounts, not knowing how to use the site, what the customs are. hoping they'll use the right tags is doomed.

New users certainly won't use the right tags if the right tags don't exist, and new users can't create new tags on their own. There's no issue with low-volume tags that are appropriate, and I don't see any issue with these not being appropriate. Someone can ask a valid question about programming using the Hikvision IS API, can they not? QED, a tag for the Hikvision IS API is warranted.

I respect your principled stand for giving users the choice of using such tags, that they couldn't create on their own. if you created those tags, even if you put these tags on existing questions, I predict that a good fraction of new questions will miss those tags, and continue to apply the wrong ones. then we're back to a bunch of mistagged questions, as well as questions with tags that call upon few to no watchers. I guess that can't be helped in any case. I guess we'll have to just give it a try? I'm skeptical.

I don't agree, [tag:hikvision-isapi] is very findable if you type "hik" into the tag box, and clearly denotes what it is. It's also an XML-based web API, so relevant for [so]. Perhaps if we retag existing questions and remove the [tag:hikvision] tag, it might be better, as that tag is too generic.

I don't think [hikvision] is too generic. it's quite specific. it collects all questions specific to their products and API. it's even more specific than most tags on this site. why do you think otherwise?

besides, we should not (I hope that's not contentious) partition the space of ideas. we should use several tags to describe the intersection. that's the normal case for any question. example: a question involving Qt and Python is not only tagged [pyqt] but [python] [qt] or perhaps [python] [qt] [pyqt]. that calls upon specialists that understand Qt in general, because their expertise is strongly applicable to the situation. I really hope I just said stuff that isn't contentious.

Because they have multiple specific APIs that are relevant, there is no other relevancy to [so], as it's just a company name, not an actual product. A bit like how we have the [tag:amazon-ec2] and [tag:amazon-web-services] but the [tag:amazon] is not used and should be removed. We wouldn't have a [tag:cocacola] tag if they had an API, we'd instead have [tag:cocacola-api].
